# How to turn OFF WiFi automatically when the app closes

Tags: java, android

I have already turned ON WiFi using this :

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager != null)
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Now I want to turn it off when I close my app I have tried by using onDestory() method it does not work guide me.

Comment: Does `wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false)` not help??

Comment: what you have tried on onDestroy?Post that code also

Comment: in onDestroy method?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
 }

Comment: Why would i want an app to disable my wifi?

Comment: this app turns on the wifi when it starts so it should have to turn it off when it closes

Comment: @spartygw well, this isn't _your_ app, is it :) if it's something that OP wants we should try our best to help

Comment: @a_local_nobody it isn't my app, but why would an app do this? Google explicitly says this is not acceptable. `This method was deprecated in API level 29. Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable Wi-Fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to `setWifiEnabled(false)` before calling `super.onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    if(wifiManager!=null) wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

note that this method is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)) in API29 and above, will return `false` and won't change WiFi state when your app will target API29 or above (which is, or will be soon, mandatory for publishing in Google Play)